# Building SPA application. Is calling RenderBody necessary?

Tags: c#, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, singlepage

I'm building `SPA` application using `Backbone.js` and as its `back-end` I want to use `ASP.NET Web API`. I need only one page and this fact brings me a lot of confusion. 
`ApiController` returns `json` response and as far as I understand there's no need in `asp.net`-specific views at all. Am I right?

Can I use plain html for my main page? Or should I use `*.cshtml` and put a call to `RenderBody` instead?

If choose the first option then how will I handle validation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the trick is that if you want search engines to be able to index your page, or people to be able to share to Facebook with a custom icon/description, etc you'll need to serve back static HTML -- none of those bots are able to run your javascript to render the page as the browser does.

If you're uninterested in this, then yes, you can completely avoid `RenderBody`.